# C, dividing a string in half

Tags: c

I am trying to write a function to divide a string in half but after the initial input it does not output anything. My goal is to scan a year and save the first two number and the last two numbers. This is the code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char scan_year2() {
  char year_number;
  scanf("%s", year_number);
  return year_number;
  return 0;
}
// Function to print n equal parts of str
void divideString(char *str, int n) {
  int str_size = strlen(str);
  int i;
  int part_size;

  if (str_size % n != 0) {
    printf("Invalid Input: String size");
    printf(" is not divisible by n");
    return;
  }

  part_size = str_size / 2;
  for (i = 0; i < str_size; i++) {
    if (i % part_size == 0)
      printf("\n");
    printf("%s", str[i]);
  }
}

int main() {
  char year_number;
  scan_year2();
  char str = year_number;
  divideString(str, 2);
  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: what did you see when you stepped through with your debugger?

Comment: Be careful with the `char` type, because it does not represent a string, but a single character instead. You need to rethink your `scan_year2` function accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that a year is at least a 3-digit number, the best way to treat it is to treat it as a number, not as a string:

```
...
int year;
scanf("%d", &year);
int first = year / 100;
int last = year % 100;
printf("%d %d\n", first, last);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

dont ignore compiler warnings, it must be complaining at you about this

```
char scan_year2() {
  char year_number;
  scanf("%s", year_number);
  return year_number;
  return 0;
}
```

you try to return twice.

Also

```
 part_size = str_size / 2;
  for (i = 0; i < str_size; i++) {
    if (i % part_size == 0)
      printf("\n");
    printf("%s", str[i]);
  }
```

is not going to give you the correct output. YOu are outputing the string each time. IE if str = "1923" then you will get

```
1923923
232
```

You should do

```
 part_size = str_size / 2;
  for (i = 0; i < str_size; i++) {
    if (i % part_size == 0)
      printf("\n");
    printf("%c", str[i]);
  }
```

to only output one char at a time